# Problems appending to a file in perl

Tags: perl, logging, append

I have problem with logging some messages in perl. I created simple log package. I still get just first row to the file. Seems like there is appending to file not working. Any ideas?

even when i run that script more times, there arent any changes in output log file. There is always just written "something". I need to append that "somethingElse"  to the output file. Do I have some mistake in log?

```
package Logger;

sub new {
  my $package = shift;
  my $self = {};
  bless $self , $package;
  $self->initialize(@_);
  return $self;
}

sub initialize {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{logfile} = shift;
  return;
}

sub logger {
  my $self = shift;
  my $message = shift;
  my (undef,$script, $line) =  caller;
  open(LOG, ">>$self->{logfile}");
  print LOG substr(scalar localtime(),4,15), " ", $message, "\n";
  close(LOG);

  return;
}


my $log = Logger->new('/usr/local/logs/test.log');
$log->logger("something");
$log->logger("somethingElse");
```

Thank you

Comment: This isn't exactly pretty code, but it _does_ work for me. Enable warnings and at least check the return value of `open` to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ditto, it works for me as well.  Running this as-is I end up with two lines in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, so I can't be sure this is the correct solution, but often when some code doesn't print what you want it to, it's because of an autoflush problem.  You could try adding this:

```
$| = 1
```

or if you prefer:

```
use English qw( -no_match_vars );
$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH = 1;
```

to the beginning of your program and see if that helps.